# In BDD/gherkin, how to use part of result, in reuseable followup step

Tags: gherkin

I have the following recurring problem which follows the following pattern:

```
Feature: api-controller

Scenario: Adding
    Given a live daemon
    When we send a POST request to /api/endpoint/ with data:
      """
      {
         "name": "foo",
      }
      """
    Then the response code should be 200
    And the response should give us a reference UUID as `uuid`
    When we send a GET request to /api/endpoint/`uuid`
    Then the response code should be 200
    ...
```

So the problem is, how do I communicate the uuid that I get from the first call, to subsequent steps, and, keep reusable steps, like the generic `When we send a GET request to [parameter1]`

I am now kind of implementing a mini language inside gherkin by defining variables using backticks, which subsequent steps should be able to access. However this feels as something either someone has already solved in a different way, or is considered bad practice because I can't find any examples of others doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look to [qaf webservice support](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/). It provides [request call repository](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki) concept where you can have parameters in request call.

[inbuilt steps](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/blob/fcd1aa874c8a577b3359ea7304adf361cbb558d9/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/step/WsStep.java#L742).

```
say {var-name} is value at jsonpath {jsonpath}
say {var-name} is value at xpath {xpath}
```

```
Feature: api-controller

Scenario: Adding
    Given a live daemon
    When user request "request.call1" with {"name": "foo"}
    Then response should have status code 200
    And say "UUID" is value at jsonpath "uuid"
    When user request "request.call2"
    Then response should have status code 200
    ...
```

All step here are available to use with [qaf webservice support](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/). In above example it uses request calls `request.call1` and `request.call2` which need to be defined in either properties file or in xml file. Below is example in xml file.

```
<requests>
  <request>
    <call1>
       <endPoint>/api/endpoint/</endPoint>
       <headers>{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}</headers>
       <method>POST</method>
       <body>{'name': '${name}'}<body>
       <parameters>
       <!--default values of parameters if not provide-->
       {
              'name':'${rnd:aaa}'
       }
       </parameters>
    </call1>
    <call2>
       <endPoint>/api/endpoint/${uuid}</endPoint>
       <headers>{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}</headers>
       <method>GET</method>
    </call2>
  </request>
</requests>
```

If you want to use cucumber you can use it with [QAF-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber)

Comment: This is conceptually the same as my approach. It seems my premise of "can't find others doing this" was wrong.